# Why do we have a symbol for the absolute value function rather than simply $\sqrt{x^2}$

Tags: absolute-value

I was looking at my calculator and saw the abs() function to which I thought, this function is fairly unnecessary. So I suppose my question is: is abs(x) different from sqrt(x^2) in some way? If they are not different, why is it so common to see abs(x) function on calculators and in programming languages etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: How is it unnecessary? Why square and then root if you can just abs (x) instead?

Comment: In programming it's way easier to return $x$ or $-x$ rather then squaring and square rooting which might even be impossible for big numbers,also you could lose precision.Other then that it's convenient to have a separate notation for abs(x)

Comment: @kingW3 Thanks! I did not think about squaring large numbers!

Comment: In any case, it's _easier_. Or do you propose removing the ² and ³-buttons too, since you can also do e.g. $x \times x \times x$...? :-)

Comment: Why make things simple when it's so simple to make them complex? Why write `3`: it could be written $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\}$?

Comment: @StackTD My point was that I and many that I know do not use the function very frequently, so it **seemed** like a waste of space (to me).

Comment: @Bernard see my comment to StackTD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, abs() just removes the sign from the number, which is computationally a LOT less expensive than squaring and the extracting the square root.  Second, extracting square roots causes round off error.

Comment: Very good point, I was thinking primarily in terms of calculator "real-estate". This makes it a much more valuable function.

Answer (score 3):

If $x$ is complex, then $|x|$ denotes the norm of $x$.  This coincides with the usual absolute value if $x$ happens to be real.  However, $\sqrt{x^2}$ differs from $|x|$ for most complex $x$ -- the former is a complex number, while the latter is always real and nonnegative.

Comment: I think this is a little confusing because the notation for norm in some texts is double bars, specifically to differentiate it from absolute value

Comment: The vertical bar is the most over-used symbol in mathematics.

Comment: This is a good point too, forgot about negative imaginary numbers. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### Generality

"Absolute value", abs(x), |x| can be always seen as an interpretation of distance - values on number line, points in space... The idea of distance makes sense in places where powers and roots do not - graphs, sets, etc. Mathematicians tend to prefer more general and abstract concepts over restricted ones.